# Use SOUNDEX function in Websql

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, chromium, web-sql

I'm trying to include this function in a websql query, something like

```
"select * from products where filter like '%pname%' order by soundex(filter);"
```

But according to this: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Soundex function is only available if sqlite was compiled with SQLITE_SOUNDEX argument, which I don't think is the case for chrome as is throwing

```
could not prepare statement (1 no such function: soundex)
```

So, my question is, is there a way to use soundex function, or at least some other similar function?

Edit 1:
For now I'm just using

```
order by coalesce(like('pname', filter), 0)
```

which is not the final solution, but better than a simple order by a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

WebSQL does not specify which SQL functions are available, and has no mechanism to install user-defined functions.

Comment: So, you're saying that there is no way to get or imitate soundex function?